# Getting this error while fetching data from localStorage(TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertRow'))

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from localStorage **after clicking submit button** but **on the first click** I am getting this error

> (TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertRow'))

And **on the second click** I am able to fetch data but I am getting the first value **is undefined**. Can anyone please suggest to me a solution (The problem is in Main.js)?

**Login.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import './Login.css';

const Login = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [pwd, setPwd] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();
    const onSubmit = () => {

        if (name === pwd && name !== "" && pwd !== "") {
            if (name in localStorage) {
                localStorage.setItem('Login', name);
                history.push(`transaction`);
            }
            else {
                localStorage.setItem('Login', name);
                localStorage.setItem(name, 0);
                history.push(`transaction`);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Please Enter a valid User");
        }
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="login loginbox">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Name</legend>
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter your name..."
                        value={name} className="text"
                        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </fieldset>
                <br />
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Password</legend>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Enter your password..."
                        value={pwd} className="text"
                        onChange={(e) => setPwd(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </fieldset>
                <button className="Loginbtn" onClick={() => onSubmit()}>Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

**Main.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import './Main.css';

const Main = () => {
    let Arr = [];
    let myArr = [];
    let recent_transaction = [];
    const [draw, setDraw] = useState('');
    const [init, setInit] = useState('');
    const [history, setHistory] = useState(false);
    const [table_show_Deposit, setTable_show_Deposit] = useState(false);
    const [table_show_WithDraw, setTable_show_WithDraw] = useState(false);
    let obj = {};
    const [collections_transaction_deposite, setCollections_transaction_deposite] = useState([obj]);
    let object = {};
    const [collections_transaction_withdraw, setCollections_transaction_withdraw] = useState([object]);
    const redirect = useHistory();
    const getter = localStorage.getItem('Login');
    let tbl = '';
    const table = <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Transaction Type</th>
                <th>Balance Amount</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Date & Time</th>
                <th>Interest</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="recenttrans">
            {tbl}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    const Deposite = () => {
        const event = new Date().toLocaleString();
        const setter = localStorage.getItem(getter)
        const store = parseInt(setter) + parseInt(init);
        localStorage.setItem(getter, store);
        let interset_Amount = '';
        if (store < 0) {
            interset_Amount = store;
        }
        else {
            interset_Amount = 0;
        }
        obj = {
            "transaction_type": 'Deposite',
            "Amount": document.getElementById('depinput').value,
            "time": event,
            "Balance": store,
            "interest": interset_Amount
        }

        setCollections_transaction_deposite(collections_transaction_deposite => [obj, ...collections_transaction_deposite])

        localStorage.setItem("transaction_Deposite", JSON.stringify(collections_transaction_deposite))

    }
    const Withdraw = () => {
        const event = new Date().toLocaleString();
        const getter = localStorage.getItem('Login')
        const setter = localStorage.getItem(getter)
        const store1 = parseInt(setter) - parseInt(draw);
        localStorage.setItem(localStorage.getItem('Login'), draw)
        localStorage.setItem(getter, store1);
        let interset_Amount = '';
        if (store1 < 0) {
            interset_Amount = store1;
        }
        else {
            interset_Amount = 0;
        }
        object = {
            "transaction_type": 'WithDraw',
            "Amount": document.getElementById('withinput').value,
            "time": event,
            "Balance": store1,
            "interest": interset_Amount
        }
        setCollections_transaction_withdraw(collections_transaction_withdraw => [object, ...collections_transaction_withdraw])

        localStorage.setItem("transaction_Withdraw", JSON.stringify(collections_transaction_withdraw))
    }
    const Deposite_show_table = () => {
        setTable_show_Deposit(true);
        setTable_show_WithDraw(false);
        if (table !== "") {
            const table = document.getElementById('deposite_table');

            myArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transaction_Deposite'));
            console.log(myArr);
            for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
                const row = table.insertRow(i);
                row.innerHTML = "<td>" + myArr[i].transaction_type + "</td>" + "<td>" + myArr[i].Amount + "</td>" + "<td>" + myArr[i].time + "</td>" + "<td>" + myArr[i].Balance + "</td>" + "<td>" + myArr[i].interest + "</td>"
            }

        }
        else {
            console.log("Empty");
        }
    }
    const WithDraw_show_table = () => {
        setTable_show_WithDraw(true);
        setTable_show_Deposit(false);
        if (table !== "") {
            const table = document.getElementById('withdrawal_table');

            Arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transaction_Withdraw'));
            console.log(Arr);
            for (let i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
                const row = table.insertRow(i);
                row.innerHTML = "<td>" + Arr[i].transaction_type + "</td>" + "<td>" + Arr[i].Amount + "</td>" + "<td>" + Arr[i].time + "</td>" + "<td>" + Arr[i].Balance + "</td>" + "<td>" + Arr[i].interest + "</td>"
            }

        }
        else {
            console.log("Empty");
        }
    }
    const RecentTrans = () => {
        debugger;
        setHistory(true);
        const deposit = [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transaction_Deposite'))];
        const withdraw = [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transaction_Withdraw'))];
        console.log(deposit);
        console.log(withdraw);
        if (table !== "") {
            const table = document.getElementById('recenttrans');
            recent_transaction = deposit[0].concat(withdraw[0]);
            console.log(recent_transaction);
            for (let i = 0; i < recent_transaction.length; i++) {
                const row = table.insertRow(i);
                row.innerHTML = "<td>" + recent_transaction[i].transaction_type + "</td>" + "<td>" + recent_transaction[i].Amount + "</td>" + "<td>" + recent_transaction[i].time + "</td>" + "<td>" + recent_transaction[i].Balance + "</td>" + "<td>" + recent_transaction[i].interest + "</td>"
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("Empty");
        }
    }
    const Signout = () => {
        redirect.push(`/`);

    }

    return (
        <div className="box">
            <div className="depmain">
                <fieldset className="fieldset">
                    <legend>Deposite</legend>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        id="depinput" className="text"
                        placeholder="Enter your money..."
                        onChange={(e) => setInit(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <button className="depbtn" onClick={() => Deposite()}>Deposit</button>
            <br />
            <div className="withmain">
                <fieldset className="fieldset">
                    <legend>WithDraw</legend>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        id="withinput" className="text"
                        placeholder="Enter your money..."
                        onChange={(e) => setDraw(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <button className="depo" onClick={() => Deposite_show_table()}>Deposite</button>
            <button className="with" onClick={() => WithDraw_show_table()}>Withdarwal</button>
            <button className="withbtn" onClick={() => Withdraw()}>WithDraw</button>
            {table_show_Deposit ? <div className="tab">
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Transaction Type</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Date & Time</th>
                            <th>Balance Amount</th>
                            <th>Interest</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="deposite_table">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> : ""}
            {table_show_WithDraw ? <div className="tab">
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Transaction Type</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Date & Time</th>
                            <th>Balance Amount</th>
                            <th>Interest</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="withdrawal_table">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> : ""}
            <div>
                <button className="recentbtn" onClick={() => RecentTrans()}>Recent Transaction</button>
                {history ?
                    <div className="tbl">{table}</div>
                    : console.log("Hello")}
            </div>
            <div>
                <button className="signbtn" onClick={() => Signout()}>Sign Out</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

> myArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transaction_Deposite'));

before parse item from localStorage check if any item setted or not.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('transaction_Deposite'))
myArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transaction_Deposite'));
```

Comment: I tried this process but it is not working for me. Can you please suggest any other solution?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either